# Not able to wrap lines in Python

Tags: python, indentation

```
else:
      fullName = curLineFin[1] + ' ' + curLineFin[2]
      players[fullName] = curLineFin[0] + '\t' + curLineFin[1] + \
      '\t' + curLineFin[2] + '\t' + curLineFin[3] + '\t' + \
      curLineFin[4] + '\t' + curLineFin[5] + '\t' + curLineFin[6] + \
      '\t' + curLineFin[7] + '\t' + curLineFin[8] + '\t' + \
      curLineFin[9] + '\t' + curLineFin[10] + '\t'
```

Every time I run the script, I get the error:

```
players[fullName] = curLineFin[0] + '\t' + curLineFin[1] + \
                                                           ^
```

IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: aren't you simply missing the \ at the end of the first line?

Comment: @BradAllred : fullName is a separate variable. The second line is setting a key to equal a value in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your code with parentheses

```
players[fullName] = (curLineFin[0] + '\t' + curLineFin[1] + 
      '\t' + curLineFin[2] + '\t' + curLineFin[3] + '\t' + 
      curLineFin[4] + '\t' + curLineFin[5] + '\t' + curLineFin[6] + 
      '\t' + curLineFin[7] + '\t' + curLineFin[8] + '\t' + 
      curLineFin[9] + '\t' + curLineFin[10] + '\t' )
```

or

```
players[fullName] = '\t'.join(curLineFin[:11]) + '\t'
```

or if this trailing tab char is not needed and you have exactly eleven elements in `curLineFin`.

```
players[fullName] = '\t'.join(curLineFin)
```

Comment: players[fullName] = (curLineFin[0] + '\t' + curLineFin[1] + \
                                                            ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

the '\' has a '^' underneath it

Comment: you don't need `\\` sign with brackets

Comment: players[fullName] = (curLineFin[0] + '\t' + curLineFin[1] + 
                                                               ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: `[]` == brackets.  `()` == parentheses.

Comment: While this is good style in general, it has **nothing to do with** the reported problem. Python misleadingly puts the `^` at the end of the line in tracebacks here, but `IndentationError` can only possibly be cause of the *indentation* of the line - i.e., the whitespace at the *beginning*. OP must  have mixed spaces and tabs (which, incidentally, is **not always detected as a `TabError` in 3.x, despite that being its purpose).

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted does not generate that error, so it's impossible to diagnose exactly what's happening in the *different* code you're actually running.

The most likely cause is that it's completely unrelated to the backslashes, and you're doing something like mixing tabs and spaces. (The fact that you're using a weird 6-character indent for the block isn't a good sign…)

Another possibility is that you're putting extra spaces after one of the backslashes. This *should* usually give you a `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`, but it's possible to confuse Python to the point where that passes and you get the following generic `SyntaxError` for a `+` with no right operand or `IndentationError` for the next line.

Comment: judging from the fact that removing 6-chars indented lines helped, i guess that was tabs

Comment: @alko: What do you mean "removing 6-chars indented lines helped"? Just copying and pasting it as-is, the code already runs just fine. (Well, you need to define `players` and `curLineFin` and put an `if False: pass` to make the `else:` work, but that's it.) Unless you have access to the OP's real code instead of what he posted here, how can you tell what helps when there's nothing to help?

Comment: i meant he accepted my answer saying `join` helped, which means error was indeed in excerpt at hand

Comment: @alko: Ah, yeah, that does prove the error was somewhere in this mess of code. But he gave us the complete traceback, with caret and everything, which was already pretty good evidence.

Answer (score 0):

Just use parenthesis:

```
fullName = (curLineFin[1] + ' ' + curLineFin[2] +
      players[fullName] = curLineFin[0] + '\t' + curLineFin[1] + 
      '\t' + curLineFin[2] + '\t' + curLineFin[3] + '\t' + 
      curLineFin[4] + '\t' + curLineFin[5] + '\t' + curLineFin[6] + 
      '\t' + curLineFin[7] + '\t' + curLineFin[8] + '\t' + 
      curLineFin[9] + '\t' + curLineFin[10] + '\t')
```